# Overriding clean(), data not accessible

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to extend an existing form so that it sends an email when it's submitted:

```
class BaseForm(forms.Form):

    field = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        "do stuff"
        return self.cleaned_data

class MyForm(BaseForm):

    def clean_field(self):
        "do some validation"
        return self.cleaned_data['field']

class MyEmailingForm(MyForm):
    def clean(self):
        super(MyEmailingForm, self).clean()
        send_mail('Form data',
          self.cleaned_data['field'],
          'Form <noreply@myform.co.uk>',
          ["formdata@myform.co.uk"],
          fail_silently=True)
```

The problem is that `self.cleaned_data['field']` is not accessible from the superclass, I get a `KeyError`. What do I need to do?

### Edit

I think I've oversimplified things. The code has been updated, I think the problem may be the double subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `self.cleaned_data` from both the base and the subclass methods.

Comment: `self.cleaned_data` is already being returned from the base method, unsurprisingly returning it from the subclass doesn't fix this particular problem.

Comment: Does `field` have a `clean_field` method? If so, can you post it?

Comment: Ok, I've clearly oversimplified things, and I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is now...

Answer (score 1):

I believe returning the self.cleaned_data to the base class only should work.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        "do stuff"
        return self.cleaned_data

    class MyEmailingForm(MyForm):
        def clean(self):
            super(MyEmailingForm, self).clean()
            send_mail('Form data',
              self.cleaned_data['field'],
              'Form <noreply@myform.co.uk>',
              ["formdata@myform.co.uk"],
              fail_silently=True)
              return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `is_valid()` method first.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: I am, but this isn't to do with the code in my view (as far as I can tell - adding the email code to the base class makes it work fine), it's to do with the code for my form.

Comment: Do you have a failing unittest?  From the original post it was difficult to determine whether or not you were accounting for this.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is not where you think it is.  It might help to include your view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the field `self.cleaned_data['field']` you are setting in base is not included in `cleaned_data`.

try

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        "do stuff with cd"
        return cd
```